# Changing the background color of a listview row conditionally

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm trying to change the background row color of a list view based on a parameter and on the line `View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent)` its giving me the error "Cannot directly invoke the abstract method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) for the type Adapter". Here is the all of the code.

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{  

LayoutInflater inflater;
List<ListViewItem> items;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<ListViewItem> items) {  
    super();

    this.items = items;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return items.size();  
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}

@Override  
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 

    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    if(convertView==null)
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_hospitals, null);
        TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView table = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView info = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info);

        status.setText(item.status);
        name.setText(item.name);
        table.setText(item.table);
        info.setText(item.info);

        if (item.status == "green"){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

    return v;  
}
}
```

Comment: Dude!  Never `item.status == "green"` in JAVA as it wont work the way you want it to,  use `"green".equals(item.status);` (this will also save you if `item == null`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change getView()

```
@Override  
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    View v=convertView;
    ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

    if(v==null){
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_hospitals, null);
    }
        TextView status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView table = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id);
        TextView info = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info);

        status.setText(item.status);
        name.setText(item.name);
        table.setText(item.table);
        info.setText(item.info);     
        String state=tem.status;


        if (state.equals("green"){
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

    return v;  
}
```

Comment: `status` is the TextView,  not a string.  this will prolly crash.

Comment: it will not work in some cases seems like you dont know that listview reuse views ...

Comment: @Selvin thanks for raising points, but i just gave a solution to fix the problem. As we can use viewHolder concept to optimise the code. Again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

well like the error says you cannot do this

```
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

instead you should be doing

```
View v = convertView;
```

then check if `v` is null

```
if(v == null){
    //get the view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i didn't understand well your question but instead of this

```
item.status == "green"
```

Use this

> item.status.equals("green")